The sum of a sequence where any term is equal to the absolute value of the difference between the prior two terms.
In a sequence, any term is equal to the absolute value of the difference between the prior two terms. Will the sum of the sequence converge? It's known that if the first two given terms are rational, the sequence will form a cycle and the sum will diverge. However, for the case of irrational numbers ($\frac{x_1}{x_2}\in R-Q$), the sum seems converge.

@lulu: I suspect the condition is really whether $\dfrac{x_1}{x_2}$ is irrational or not.  (If both are $0$ then the sequence and sum converge while if exactly one is $0$ then they do not.)

@Henry You are right. I was unclear

You get a sequence closely related to the continued fraction.  Say there is a sequence with
$$a_0=a,a_1=b,a_{n-1}=M_na_n+a_{n+1}$$
Your series has
$$a_{n-1}-ka_n,a_n,a_{n-1}-(k+1)a_n,a_{n-1}-(k+2)a_n,a_n,\ldots$$
There are $M_n$ terms whose average value is around $a_{n-1}/2$.  Their sum is about $$a_{n-1}^2/(2a_n)$$
So, if the $a_n$ shrink fast enough, the sum can increase without limit.
